# R: source() not calling file name but is calling working director url

Tags: r

I have a script saved on working directory "C:Users/u338499/Desktop/r". The file name is "test.R". getwd() will return exactly the URL above.

On the console, when I call the script using the full URL (ie source("C:Users/u338499/Desktop/r/test.r")), the script runs successfully. However, when I call it using just the file name "source(test.R)" or "source(test.r)", it says "Error in source(test.R) : object 'test.R' not found."

Anyone know why calling the source method using just the file name is not working? (note as above, my working directory is set to the 'r' folder and I definitely have the test.r file in there).

Comment: I believe you will find that you need to use C:/Users... You are missing the / between C: and Users.

Comment: Did you try using quotes around the filename when using source("test.R")

Comment: Yeah, when I use the quotation mark, I get the following message: Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'test.R': No such file or directory

Comment: I found what what was wrong. @earion, thanks I set my wd wrong by not including the / character. And thanks Marichyasana as I also was not using the quotation mark when calling the script.